# Using same database table with different alias to retrieve data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here what I am trying to do is to get the values for P1,P2,P3 that should comes from A3, 
this works well for two tables but not for three...

```
SELECT x.A1,x.A3,x.A4,A5,A6, x.A2 as P1,y.A2 as P2,z.A2 as P3
FROM Contact x,Contact y,Contact z
WHERE (x.id = y.id) AND (y.id = z.id)   AND
(x.A3 ='pre-sale') AND (y.A3= pos-sale') AND(z.A3='current-sale') 
 ORDER by x.A4 DESC
```

For example
     the CONTACT table will look like this with some expected results for P1,P2, P3

```
 A1   A2       A3         A4     A5   A6   P1  P2 P3 
 ----------------------------------------------------
 1    22     pre-sale     9     kk    8    22  31  2 
 2    31     pos-sale     4     yy    6    44  61  11
 3    2      current-sale 1     hh    2    null null null
 4    44     pre-sale     2     kk    8      
 5    61     pos-sale     1     yy    6      
 6    11     current-sale 1     hh    2
```

For P1, P2 using twice same table works well, adding the third table the values 
     for P1, P2 are   the same and for P3 all null

Comment: Don't use that outdated join syntax

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you are trying to do might best be done with conditional aggregation.  It is a bit hard to tell what you are really trying to accomplish, because not all the columns are aliased.  Here is an example

```
SELECT c.id,
       max(case when c.A3 = 'pre-sale' then A4 end) as PreSale_A4,
       max(case when c.A3 = 'pos-sale' then A2 end) as PosSale_A2,
       max(case when c.A3 = 'current-sale' then A4 end) as CurrentSale_A2
FROM Contact c
group by c.id
order by PreSale_A4 desc;
```

Your original query has some fundamental problems.  For instance, you are using implicit joins via the `where` clause, which are always inner joins.  The solution to your problem might be using outer joins instead.  Conditional aggregation probably solves the problem, though.